# Windows SSH file transfer?

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, transfer

Is there a way to do file transfers on a remote PC (off the LAN) using something similar to the unix/Linux SCP command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few tools that you could use. There's the Putty collection including [pscp and psftp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). For GUI clients, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) and [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) are pretty good. And of course, Cygwin is also an option.

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) is a good one (and free). It has a console mode version as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it "Linux style", install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and add scp (I believe it's part of the SSH package).

Answer (score 1):

[Pscp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

```
pscp <windows path where the file exists> username@linuxMachineAddress<path>
```

For example

```
pscp C:\Documents\helloWorld.txt firdooze@165.1.122.76:/home/firdooze/Desktop/.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicely packaged cygwin/rsync + GUI tool - [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

From the Web site:

- Incremental backup - Copies part of the file that is actually modified
- Task scheduler - Profiles in DeltaCopy can run based on a schedule
- Email notification - Administrators can receive email confirmation on successful as well as failed transfers
- One-click restore - Backed up files can be easily restored.
- Windows friendly environment - No need to manually modify configuration files or play around with command line options.